# Xeditable checklist not store data

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

i use xeditable for angular. I make form-list for edit user, everything works fine, only check list make me problems :)
I use xeditable check list, like this one https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#checklist , and get data from api. Anything i select, is not sending to api with rest data from form. If i use  `editable-select="user.status" e-multiple` instead of `editable-checklist="user.status"`, work's fine. But for my app i need to use multiple checklist. Here is (not working) [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jTtTBRneEELSxjrbT8up?p=preview) of my project, for this part with dummy data. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

i find solution, on xeditable web page. I need to add `checklist-model` to app module, and include `checklist-model.js` directive.

> But in practice we usually want one model to store array of checked values from several checkboxes. Checklist-model solves that task without additional code in controller. You should play with attributes of  tag:
>    - set checklist-model instead of ng-model 
>    - set checklist-value - what    should be picked as array item